# Python: absolute path error in mac

Tags: python

I am using python on mac and would like to open a pdf file that is present in different directory than the directory my main python code is running. I tried different options but there is always an error saying file doesn't exist even when the file is present or [Error no. 2] file cannot be opened. Here is the code that I use:

```
helpFile = os.path.abspath('~/help/help.pdf')
self.help_btn = tk.Button(self.help_frm, text="Help!", width=8, command = lambda: os.system("open "+helpFile))
```

could some one help please.

Comment: That code has a lot going on - TkInter, lambda, os.path.abspath, etc. I would simplify it to code that simply tries to open and read a file. That way, you can ask the question more simply, and also it'll be easy to spot the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`abspath` does not expand `~` into the user's home directory, it just calculates the absolute path of a file based on its path relative to the current working directory.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), it is equivalent to:

```
normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))
```

So in your code, `helpFile` is being set to `"/path/to/cwd/~/help/help.pdf"`

To expand `~`, use `os.path.expanduser`.